# database data to CSV nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, web

The below Code show how to download users data in CSV file.
the issue is the output of the data inside the CSV is not organized.

**app.js file**

```
  app.get('/export-csv',function(req,res){
      db.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err, users, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("users:");
    
        const jsonUsers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users));
        //console.log(jsonUsers);
     
        // -> Convert JSON to CSV data
        const csvFields = ['id', 'name', 'shopCode','region'];
        const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ csvFields });
        const csv = json2csvParser.parse(jsonUsers);
     
        //console.log(users);
     
         res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
         res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=users.csv");
     
         res.status(200).end(csv);
      });
    });
```

[image]

what am I missing, how to make the data organized inside CSV ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Instead of

```
        const csvFields = ['id', 'name', 'shopCode','region'];
        const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ csvFields });
        const csv = json2csvParser.parse(jsonUsers);
```

To

```
        var fields = ['id', 'name', 'shopCode','region'];
        var fieldNames = ['Id', 'Name', 'ShopCode','Region'];
        var csv = json2csv({ data: docs, fields: fields, fieldNames: fieldNames });
```

and install `json2csv` npm. Hope it will work.

Comment: I did but error appear: json2csv is not defined

Comment: Also, I install as you asked.